# Dependency failing: In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version

Tags: android, gradle

I updated version of libraries to the newest and getting error now:

```
org.gradle.api.GradleException: In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[16.3.
0]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

Dependency failing: com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector-impl:17.0.5 -> com.google.firebase:firebase-analy
tics@[16.3.0], but firebase-analytics version was 17.2.0.

The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
ifact with the issue.
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-core@17.2.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector-impl@17.0.5
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics@{strictly 17.2.0}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector-impl@{strictly 17.0.5}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics@17.2.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-ads@18.2.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-core@{strictly 17.2.0}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-ads@{strictly 18.2.0}
```

Gradle file contains following Firebase libraries:

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.2.0'
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.0.2'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.0'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
 implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector-impl:17.0.5'
```

Comment: Why are you declaring a direct dependency on `firebase-measurement-connector-impl` at all?

Comment: @ianhanniballake previously I had the same problems and found a solution to specify it directly, now I tried to remove it and update all libraries to the latest versions, but after all migration (also to androidx) I got another issue with dagger versions...